# 5 input and 3 output features for machine learning

Tags: machine-learning, tensorflow, neural-network, regression

Need some advise here.

I am trying to build a model where it can predict the 3 different output features when 5 input features are given.

for example, 
5 input features: size of the house, house floor, house condition, number of rooms, parking. 
3 output features: price for selling, price for buying,  price for renting

What I am confusing right now is that, is that possible that the trained model are able to predict the 3 outputs? What I found from others' example/tutorial is that they mostly trying to do one thing only on their model.

Sorry if my explanations are bad, I am new to tensorflow and machine learning.

Comment: Yes. It is possible

Comment: Yes. Its called multi-label classification or regression

Comment: @VivekKumar, thank you for directing to toward multi-label classification. Further study from your answer, I found [link](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/multiclass.html) and think my problem are more related to multi-output regression, or even multiclass-multioutput classification.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Neural network definitely can predict/approximate more outputs. I have experience with neuron regulator and there net produce control signal for two motors.

So I don't have experience with tensorflow. But this framework is from Google and is quite popular, so I'm almost sure, there is multioutput functionality.

There is nice example [of such thing.](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1609.07378.pdf)

Comment: my quick study found multi-output regression is quite near to my problem I guess. Is there any library that offer a good multi-output regression or multiclass-multioutput classification functionality?

Comment: I build neural nets on my own, so I haven't experience with libraries, but from my viev, multiclassification is such basic thing. All good libraries must have something like multiouutput classification, there is Tensorflow, Keras, Matlab neural toolbox...

Answer (score 1):

In common practice, we build a model to predict only one output, that is because in surpervised learning, we should input some certain kinds of variables, and find a relation between them with a wanted output. Because this relation generally cannot work between the input and another wanted output.

But we can have a special technique to fit your problem:

If we have four input variables : I1, I2, I3, I4, and we want three output lables (generally discrete): O1, O2, O3. so we can created a new lable O4 after mergering the original three outputs. For example, if O1, O2, O3 can onlt be 0 or 1, the O4 have 2^3, in total, 8 possible values. So, we can build a prediction model between four input variables and the output O4. And once value of O4 is known, O1-O3 are all known as well.

Howover, if the output variable are not all discrete, especially regression technique is used, the technique above wonnot work. So, to predict three output, we normally do training three times and make three models.